# How to export pins with GPIOD

Tags: embedded-linux

We're using Colibri IMx6 and we need to access few pins.
Back in the sysfs days, we were able to just echo the export to a "file" on a system and the pin would get "activated".

Now I'm wondering how I would export pins as GPIO with the "new" GPIOD

`cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio` output:

```
gpiochip0: GPIOs 0-31, parent: platform/209c000.gpio, 209c000.gpio:

gpiochip1: GPIOs 32-63, parent: platform/20a0000.gpio, 20a0000.gpio:
 gpio-37  (                    |cd                  ) in  hi IRQ
 gpio-54  (                    |Wake-Up             ) in  lo IRQ

gpiochip2: GPIOs 64-95, parent: platform/20a4000.gpio, 20a4000.gpio:
 gpio-90  (                    |enable              ) out hi    
 gpio-95  (                    |usb_host_vbus       ) out lo    

gpiochip3: GPIOs 96-127, parent: platform/20a8000.gpio, 20a8000.gpio:
 gpio-108 (                    |scl                 ) in  hi    
 gpio-109 (                    |sda                 ) in  hi    

gpiochip4: GPIOs 128-159, parent: platform/20ac000.gpio, 20ac000.gpio:
 gpio-130 (                    |spi_imx             ) out hi    

gpiochip5: GPIOs 160-191, parent: platform/20b0000.gpio, 20b0000.gpio:

gpiochip6: GPIOs 192-223, parent: platform/20b4000.gpio, 20b4000.gpio:
 gpio-204 (                    |id                  ) in  lo IRQ
```

We'd need to export about 6 pins on the `gpiochip0`, but if they're not exported, we can set them all we want with GPIOD-cli-tools, but they won't change on the hardware, or the hardware won't report for the input pins.

We set and query GPIO pins via GPIOD's CLI tools

```
# gpioset  --mode=signal 2 4=1
# gpioset  --mode=time --sec=50 2 4=1
```

but the LED doesn't turn on

## Start EDIT

`gpioinfo 2` output while the `gpioset --mode=signal 2 4=1` is active:

```
gpiochip2 - 32 lines:
        line   0:      unnamed       unused   input  active-high
        line   1:      unnamed       unused  output  active-high
        line   2:      unnamed       unused  output  active-high
        line   3:      unnamed       unused  output  active-high
        line   4:      unnamed    "gpioset"  output  active-high [used]
        line   5:      unnamed       unused  output  active-high
        line   6:      unnamed       unused  output  active-high
...
```

## End EDIT

and for the query(button), we use the following

```
# gpioget 0 29
0
```

which returns `0` no matter what state the button is in.

## Edit

After further inspection, we figured out, that the only pin that wasn't working was pin 67, and that's because of the multiplexing.
Now my question changes to: How can I disable the multiplexing on the pin 67 and make it work as a GPIO pin 17 on the gpiochip2

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the pin was that that pin is MUX-ed and you need to disable the MUX with the DeviceTree, to use the GPIO function of that pin.